# Openssl on Git Bash fails with error when Heredoc is used

Tags: bash, openssl, cygwin, here-document

I have a script that is generating ssl certificates for me. The screen used to work fine on my computer before and I did not change the script since I used it last time. Today I ran the script and noticed a buggy behaviour. After running the script the terminal does no longer print out characters that I type into the console. I have to close and reopen Git Bash.

I tried to find the source of the issue and finally extracted the following command:

```
openssl req -new -key foobar.key -out foobar.csr -config <(cat <<EOF
[req]
default_bits = 2048
EOF
)
```

When I run that, the following output is printed:

> error on line -1 of /proc/6180/fd/63
>   2292:error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process:bss_file.c:175:fopen('/proc/6180/fd/63','rb')
>   2292:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:bss_file.c:182:
>   2292:error:0E078072:configuration file routines:DEF_LOAD:no such file:conf_def.c:201:

When I put the content of the heredoc into a file and pass that as a parameter to `-config` then the issue goes away. I cannot explain what has changed on my computer that causes this issue. How can I debug this further?

Comment: Verify that the script is in fact executed by `bash`. If it has a `#!`-line, that should contain the path to the `bash` executable (not `sh`). If you explicitly tell the shell what interpreter you use on the command line, you should use `bash ./script`, not `sh ./script`.

Comment: The script has `#!/bin/bash` on the first line. If I execute the above commend directly from a bash shell I get the same behaviour.

Comment: After investigating this further I can confirm that the script runs just fine on a linux box, there must be some issue with the environment on windows (e.g. Git Bash, Cygwin, MSYS2, etc..). I should note that I have a separate MSYS2 install on the same computer which has the same problem. Previously I was able to execute my script in both Git Bash and MSYS2 without these problems.

Comment: It has something to do with the `bash` you are using. The default `bash` in Cygwin handles process substitutions and here-documents within these without problems.

Comment: In MinGW with `bash` I get `bash: cannot make pipe for process substitution: Function not implemented`.

Comment: Do you have an idea how I can further narrow down the source of this issue ?

Comment: Not really, but the easiest solution would be to write the here-document to file and use that before deleting it again. This is what `bash` does in the background anyway.